# Is there a stable way to tell Rustfmt to skip an entire file

Tags: rust, rustfmt

The official way to get Rustfmt to skip an item is `#[rustfmt::skip]`, however I want it to skip an entire file. I tried this:

```
#![rustfmt::skip]
```

However you get this error

> error[E0658]: non-builtin inner attributes are unstable

[Here is the issue for that error.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54726)

Is there a workaround for this? Solutions I am not interested in:

- Use unstable Rust
- Tell Rustfmt not to process the file using something external to the file (`rustfmt.toml` for example)

Comment: Put it as an outer attribute I guess?

Comment: Ah yes that does seem to be the way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently Rustfmt traverses the mod tree itself so you can put the attribute on the file that declared the module you want to ignore.

```
#[rustfmt::skip]
mod dont_format_this_file;
```

Then `dont_format_this_file.rs` will be skipped.

However, Rustfmt 2 [changed its behaviour](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/commit/09a028b64d04b720fa55aac0594688bb291297cd) so that it *doesn't* traverse the mod tree, so you have to specify `dont_format_this_file.rs` directly. In that case it seems likely that it will find the `mod dont_format_this_file;` declaration so this may not work when Rustfmt 2 is released.

Answer (score 3):

To skip an entire file you can add this to the top of the file:

```
#![cfg_attr(rustfmt, rustfmt_skip)]
```

This attribute is outlined in the tips section of the [rustfmt nightly docs](https://crates.io/crates/rustfmt-nightly/0.6.1). It just worked in my case but I'm unsure if thats because I'm using nightly or something.