# Format multi-line string literal arguments without extra lines

Tags: rust, configuration, code-formatting, rustfmt

I would like to call macros with a single multi-line string argument, formatted like so:

```rust
css!(r"
    background: grey;
    color: white;
");
```

However, Rustfmt insists on putting the string literal on its own line, which is ugly and takes up more space:

```rust
css!(
    r"
    background: grey;
    color: white;
"
);
```

Is there a way I can tell Rustfmt to not put a single string literal on its own line, even when it has multiple lines?

I am aware that Rustfmt can be [configured](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=v1.4.38&search=), but I couldn't find an option for this and I don't really know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#[rustfmt::skip]` to tell rustfmt to not format code:

```rust
#[rustfmt::skip]
css!(r"
background: grey;
color: white;
");
```

rustfmt also skips braced macros, so you can do:

```rust
css! { r"
background: grey;
color: white;
" };
```

You can also use `#[rustfmt::skip::macros(...)]` to always skip this macro:

```rust
#[rustfmt::skip::macros(css)]
fn foo() { ... }
```

To apply it whole-file (see [Is there a stable way to tell Rustfmt to skip an entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247458/is-there-a-stable-way-to-tell-rustfmt-to-skip-an-entire-file)), you can either apply it to the module declaration, or use an inner attribute, but that's unstable:

```rust
#![feature(custom_inner_attributes)]
#![rustfmt::skip::macros(css)]
```